# Bind Xaml DataGrid to first item in sub-array

Tags: xaml, binding, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid which is bound to an array of objects.
These objects contain some properties and another array of items, like this:

```
public class MySubClass
{
  public String SubItem {get;set;}
}

public class MyContrievedSampleCollection
{
  public String Name {get;set;}
  public ObservableCollection<MySubClass> Sublist {get; set;}
}
```

So I bind the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection, which works nicely:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I want to add another column which is bound to a property in the first item of the Sublist:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subitem" Binding="{Binding Sublist[0].Subitem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Subitem" Binding="{Binding Sublist[0].Subitem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

should work, but..

1) It may be required to convert your Subitem to a DependencyProperty or at least implement INotifyPropertyChanged in MySubClass (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx for that).

2) You can loose the binding, if the item at index 0 is deleted (or changed; not sure, if ObservableCollection takes care of that). You should bind to properties that always exist.

Comment: Oh dang. So my Problem is somewhere else :/